# Can't get Eclipse Kepler CheckStyle plugin to work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I am downloading it from here: http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/update/
- Checkstyle version 6.2.0.20150

My eclipse build is: 4.3.2

I have tried downloading it from both the marketplace and the website above, though both ways do not create a "checkstyle" link in the preferences window.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I cannot see any errors logged (Error Log view) and installed software list shows checkstyle plugin which is weird because the installed plugins doesn't show the checkstyle plugin.

Comment: @SukenShah probably it was caused by too old Java version. Minimal supported is Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered the mentioned problem. But the reason is simple. In the [release notes](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/releasenotes) we can read:

> Please note that as of this version **Java 7 is the minimum runtime
>   environment supported**. This requires you to run Eclipse on a Java 7
>   (or newer) JVM in order to use this plugin version.

Checkstyle since version 6.2.0 (released in January 2015) needs **Java 7** as the minimum runtime environment.

So in order to run Eclipse on a Java 7, you can for example edit `eclipse.ini` file and add at the beginning something like:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\javaw.exe
```

Your exact path to `javaw.exe` could be different, of course. Alternatively make JDK 7 (or newer) as the default JVM for your system.